# Adding multiple listeners to one EventEmitter on Node server

Tags: node.js, httprequest, eventemitter

I have node.js server, and clients connecting by AJAX HTTP long polling request.
I want to create one EventEmitter object and I want to add every new client to this object after received request from him.
What is proper way to do this? In other words: How use "emitter.on(event, listener)" in function runs for every client to have them all waiting in EventEmitter listeners array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably easier to have just one event emitter listener and have an array of waiting long polling requests.  Then, you are free to add/remove items from the array at any time as connections come and go and there's just one listener that processes whatever requests are in the array when an event occurs.